# PHP json processing into array

Tags: php, arrays, json, formatting

I am trying to parse an array of all the no's out of this JSON:

```
[{"page":1,"threads":[{"no":20783566,"last_modified":1417023255},{"no":20789075,"last_modified":1417023250},{"no":20777699,"last_modified":1417023250}]},{"page":2,"threads":[{"no":20753588,"last_modified":1417023105},{"no":20784845,"last_modified":1417023103},{"no":20789489,"last_modified":1417023099},{"no":20788012,"last_modified":1417023074}]}]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$array = json_decode($rawjson, true);

$threads = array();
$threadids = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
    array_push($threads, $array[$i]['threads']);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($threads); ++$i) {
    array_push($threadids, $threads[$i]['no']);
}
```

I know that the first `for` statement doesn't work like it is supposed to, I need array_push to not create an array inside the original array, but I don't know how to go about doing that.
I can't get the second `for` statement to work because I need to loop inside each array...

The final result I want is an array of just the `no` values. I don't want any of the array formatting. If someone knows of a better way to go about doing so, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're wanting is...

```
$array = json_decode($rawjson, true);

$threads = array();
$threadids = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
  array_push($threads, $array[$i]['threads']);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($threads); ++$i) {
  foreach ($threads[$i] as $thread) {
    array_push($threadids, $thread['no']);
  }
}
```

Use [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) to see what your arrays look like.  It will save your life!

Better yet... (personally I prefer foreach in these types of situations)

```
$array = json_decode($rawjson, true);

$threads = array();
$threadids = array();

foreach ($array as $page) {
    array_push($threads, $page['threads']);
}

foreach($threads as $temp) {
  foreach ($temp as $thread) {
    array_push($threadids, $thread['no']);
  }
}
```